# PSQL regex: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Tags: regex, psql

I'm trying to create a table where in the constraint is that the name to be added needs to be in the form "abc-123". I'm trying to do this by using `CONSTRAINT pname CHECK(pname ~ '^[A-Za-z]+(?(?=\.)[a-z]+|)\-[0-9]*$')`. However, when I try to insert anything into the table (for eg. (1,'name-123','blue') it gives me the error `invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid` and I'm unsure why or how to fix it.

Comment: Why not `^[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+$`? What are the rules you try to implement in the regex?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!